# can't use periods in ServerName [Lion Apache installation]

Tags: apache-2.2, hostname

I can access my host like this…

```
http://keggyshop
```

but can't use periods…

```
http://keggyshop.dev
```

here's my virtual host directive…

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName keggyshop
    ServerAlias keggyshop.dev
    DocumentRoot "~/sites/2012/keggy/web/pages/keggy/120528/sandbox/public"

    <Directory "~/sites/2012/keggy/web/pages/keggy/120528/sandbox/public">
            Options Includes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

host file

```
127.0.0.1    keggyshop
127.0.0.1    keggyshop.dev
```

traceroute for keggyshop…

```
user$ traceroute keggyshop
traceroute to keggyshop (192.168.1.184), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  keggyshop (192.168.1.184)  1.188 ms  0.683 ms  0.747 ms
```

traceroute for keggyshop.dev…

```
user$ traceroute keggyshop.dev
traceroute: Warning: keggyshop.dev has multiple addresses; using 184.106.15.239
traceroute to keggyshop.dev (184.106.15.239), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  * 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  0.856 ms  0.568 ms
2  10.81.192.1 (10.81.192.1)  15.232 ms  7.002 ms  7.936 ms
3  gig-0-3-0-6-nycmnya-rtr2.nyc.rr.com (24.29.97.122)  7.962 ms  7.813 ms  7.712 ms
4  bun101.nycmnytg-rtr001.nyc.rr.com (184.152.112.107)  10.999 ms  14.001 ms  15.466 ms
5  bun6-nycmnytg-rtr002.nyc.rr.com (24.29.148.250)  11.231 ms  17.321 ms  12.745 ms
6  107.14.19.24 (107.14.19.24)  13.972 ms  11.704 ms  16.477 ms
7  ae-1-0.pr0.nyc30.tbone.rr.com (66.109.6.161)  9.237 ms  11.896 ms
   107.14.19.153 (107.14.19.153)  7.481 ms
8  xe-5-0-6.ar2.ewr1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.94.57)  16.682 ms  11.791 ms  11.981 ms
9  ae3-90g.cr1.ewr1.us.nlayer.net (69.31.94.117)  12.977 ms  15.706 ms  9.709 ms
10  xe-5-0-0.cr1.ord1.us.nlayer.net (69.22.142.74)  30.473 ms  30.497 ms  31.750 ms
11  ae1-20g.ar1.ord6.us.nlayer.net (69.31.110.250)  36.699 ms  50.785 ms  35.957 ms
12  as19994.xe-1-0-7.ar1.ord6.us.nlayer.net (69.31.110.242)  34.723 ms  31.118 ms  29.967 ms
13  coreb.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.138)  30.471 ms
    corea.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.136)  33.392 ms  35.210 ms
14  core1-coreb.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.129)  32.453 ms
    core1-corea.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.125)  32.020 ms
    core1-coreb.ord1.rackspace.net (184.106.126.129)  32.417 ms
15  core1-aggr401a-3.ord1.rackspace.net (173.203.0.157)  31.274 ms  34.854 ms  30.194 ms
```

Comment: your examples don't match your virtual host directive, can you be more clear about what doesn't work, and where from, and what errors or messages you get.

Comment: updated. i removed the server alias. so i changed my server name to keggyshop.edu. still not working

Comment: Is keggyshop.edu actually a resolvable hostname on your computer?  Is there a DNS or host file entry to turn it into an IP address?

Comment: It's also good practice not to use a name that could resolve into a valid DNS name, so using `.edu` as a suffix is a bad idea.

Comment: ok, i've changed the hostname to '.dev' and included the host file above. still no go

Answer (score 3):

You need to be careful when using periods (dots) in DNS names. The period has special meaning and it should not be handled like any othher character.

Anyway, you need to make sure the name you are using is resolvable by your clients (preferably via DNS server). You can use hosts file for testing purposes and in your local environment. Then, you can verify your web server config to match specific name(s).

Comment: this is for my development environment. i removed all other virtual hosts and removed the server alias. so now my server name is keggyshop.edu and it still doesn't work

Comment: @punchfacechamp: Can you ping this name?

Comment: yes, for some reason keggyshop.dev resolves to 184.106.15.239 which is a public ip i've never seen. isn't a valid location

Comment: see the traceroute i added above

Comment: SOLVED - host file was corrupt. created a new one from scratch and it worked. perhaps it was because i edited the host file with textmate? anyway, thanks to all who contributed!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you don't understand.

More specifically with the .dev resolving to something other that 127.0.0.1 you have a name resolution problem, not a vhost problem.

You will need to find out why the keggyshop.dev is resolving to multiple addresses and fix it so that it only resolves to 127.0.0.1